# When i add more row to a table OnClick it displays but in wrong way

Tags: javascript, css

I want to add more row to a table. When I click on a button, it works, except when it gets added it looks broken.

Here's the code I'm using:

```js
document.querySelector('#addmore').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var el = document.querySelector('#someID');
  el.style.display = el.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
})
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="addmore">Add more</button>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="someID" style="display: none;">
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

I've also created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c93qj117/) of this.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element that you are trying to show (`#someID`) is a `<tr>` (table row) yet you are setting it's display property to `block`. You should be setting it to `table-row`.

```js
document.querySelector('#addmore').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var el = document.querySelector('#someID');
  el.style.display = el.style.display === 'none' ? 'table-row' : 'none';
})
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<button id="addmore">Add more</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="someID" style="display: none;">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display: 'table-row'

```
 el.style.display = el.style.display === 'none' ? 'table-row' : 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

### See Below Example:

Note: You should delete "block" from your javascript section & just use block quote like '';

```js
document.querySelector('#addmore').addEventListener('click', function () {
 var el = document.querySelector('#someID');
  el.style.display = el.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
})
```

```css
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
```

```html
<body>
 <button id="addmore" >Add more</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="someID" style="display: none;">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
 
 
</table>
```